# Write Spark dataframe as CSV with partitions

Tags: csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, partitioning

I'm trying to write a dataframe in spark to an HDFS location and I expect that if I'm adding the `partitionBy` notation Spark will create partition 
(similar to writing in Parquet format)
folder in form of

```
partition_column_name=partition_value
```

( i.e `partition_date=2016-05-03`). To do so, I ran the following command :

```py
(df.write
    .partitionBy('partition_date')
    .mode('overwrite')
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .save('/tmp/af_organic'))
```

but partition folders had not been created
any idea what sould I do in order for spark DF automatically create those folders?

Thanks,

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Spark 2.0.0+**:

Built-in csv format supports partitioning out of the box so you should be able to simply use:

```
df.write.partitionBy('partition_date').mode(mode).format("csv").save(path)
```

**without including any additional packages**.

**Spark < 2.0.0**:

At this moment (v1.4.0) `spark-csv` doesn't support `partitionBy` (see [databricks/spark-csv#123](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/issues/123)) but you can adjust built-in sources to achieve what you want.

You can try two different approaches. Assuming your data is relatively simple (no complex strings and need for character escaping) and looks more or less like this:

```py
df = sc.parallelize([
    ("foo", 1, 2.0, 4.0), ("bar", -1, 3.5, -0.1)
]).toDF(["k", "x1", "x2", "x3"])
```

You can manually prepare values for writing:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, concat_ws

key = col("k")
values = concat_ws(",", *[col(x) for x in df.columns[1:]])

kvs = df.select(key, values)
```

and write using `text` source

```py
kvs.write.partitionBy("k").text("/tmp/foo")

df_foo = (sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .options(inferSchema="true")
    .load("/tmp/foo/k=foo"))

df_foo.printSchema()
## root
## |-- C0: integer (nullable = true)
## |-- C1: double (nullable = true)
## |-- C2: double (nullable = true)
```

In more complex cases you can try to use proper CSV parser to preprocess values in a similar way, either by using UDF or mapping over RDD, but it will be significantly more expensive.

If CSV format is not a hard requirement you can also use JSON writer which supports `partitionBy` out-of-the-box:

```py
df.write.partitionBy("k").json("/tmp/bar")
```

as well as partition discovery on read.