# spark - write to separate files by key

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My code:

```
df.write.partitionBy("col").format("json").save(output)
```

then my output:

```
col=1
col=2
col=3
```

I need a csv format, but when I changed the `format("json")` to `format("csv")` I don't have separate files, but one file with all data

```
part-00000
```

why? and how can I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [write spark dataframe as CSV with partitions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37509932/write-spark-dataframe-as-csv-with-partitions)