# Divide Spark dataframe into many CSV files

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a large Spark dataframe (150G):

```
val1   val2   val3
 a      2      hello
 b      1      hi
 a      1      he
 a      7      hen
 b      5      ha
 ....
```

I want to save this dataframe to many CSV files quickly, and every CSV file has only one kind val1 and **sorted** based on val2. So the output should be:

1.csv:

```
val1   val2   val3
 a      1      he
 a      2      hello
 a      7      hen
 ...
```

2.csv:

```
val1   val2   val3 
 b      1      hi
 b      5      ha
 ....
```

Python version solution is best, thank you!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is asking us to do the work and not showing any self-trying

Comment: @SynerCoder Please note that lack of effort from the OP is *not* a valid reason to close a question.

Comment: If your data is partitioned, you basically can do this for free https://stackoverflow.com/q/37509932/792066

Comment: @cigien yes it is, SO is an "I ran into a problem programming" site, not a "I think this problem can be solved programming, fix it for me" site. SO is here to help you a problem in your code, not here to write all the code for you.

Comment: @SynerCoder You are referring to debugging problems, which are just a subset of the questions that can be asked. "How-to" questions where the OP asks for code is also perfectly fine, so long as the problem is narrowly scoped. This question is an example of the kind of "how-to" questions that are allowed. You can discuss whether this is the case and/or if this is a good idea on [meta]. This has been discussed before so I suggest researching a bit before asking a question, if you choose to do that.

Comment: @cigien I see this as the type of "homework" question where no effort is made by the OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first repartition the dataframe by `val1`, then sort `val2` within each partition, and finally write csv outputs partitioned by `val1`.

```
df.repartition('val1').sortWithinPartitions('val2').write.partitionBy('val1').csv('output', header=True)
```

Comment: hi, but I find that your way can't make whole dataset sorted by 'val2'

Comment: Why do you want to sort the whole dataset if you're splitting by val1? If you want to sort the whole dataset, use `df.sort('val2')`.

Comment: thanks,so I need use df.sort('val2) first,and then use df.repartition('va1') to get .csv files?

Comment: If you want to split by val1, then you should sort by val2 after splitting. Sorting by val2 before or after splitting by val1 is identical.

Comment: thank you for your patience,maybe I didn't express my problem well. I just want to split one big file into many files based on one index,for example, 'va1'. And in every splitted file, like 1.csv, the val2 is sorted. If I use df.sort('val2') and partition df into many files using df.repartition('va1').write.partitionBy('va1').csv('output',header = True), yes I truly get many files, for example, xxx.csv in 'va1=***' directory, but the xxx.csv is not sorted on ‘val2' actually.

Comment: Then you can refer to the code in my answer.